# Creating a new variable using dplyr in R using lists

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

So let's say we have three lists.

```
list_A <- c("PA","MA","MD")
list_B <- c("NJ","NY","OK")
list_C <- c("AZ","MT","LA")
```

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID        presenter          state   
1         Donatello   c("AZ","NY")
2          Leonardo             NJ
3            Rafael   c("LA","MT")
4     Michaelangelo    c("PA,"LA")
```

I want to use the tidyverse to create three new vars which count how many times `state` contains an element of their list for each row.

```
ID        presenter          state     A   B   C   
1         Donatello   c("AZ","NY")     0   1   1
2          Leonardo             NJ     0   1   0
3            Rafael   c("LA","MT")     0   0   2
4     Michaelangelo   c("PA","LA")     1   0   1
```

Unrelated but related, but out of curiousity, is it possible to unlist() the state but make more rows with the old info, so manipulating df1...

```
ID        presenter          state   
1         Donatello             AZ
1         Donatello             NY
2          Leonardo             NJ
3            Rafael             LA
3            Rafael             MT
4     Michaelangelo             PA
4     Michaelangelo             LA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double `sapply` :

```
list_data <- list(list_A, list_B, list_C)
cbind(df1, data.frame(sapply(list_data, function(x) 
           sapply(df1$state, function(y) sum(y %in% x)))))


#     ID presenter     state        X1    X2    X3
#  <int> <chr>         <list>    <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 Donatello     <chr [2]>     0     1     1
#2     2 Leonardo      <chr [1]>     0     1     0
#3     3 Rafael        <chr [2]>     0     0     2
#4     4 Michaelangelo <chr [2]>     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this regarding your first question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

list_A <- c("PA","MA","MD")
list_B <- c("NJ","NY","OK")
list_C <- c("AZ","MT","LA")


data <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  presenter = c("Donatello", "Leonardo", "Rafael", "Michaelangelo"),
  state = list(c("AZ", "NJ"), c("NJ"), c("LA", "MT"), c("PA", "LA"))
)

data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(A = sum(list_A %in% state),
         B = sum(list_B %in% state),
         C = sum(list_C %in% state))
```

With this output:

```
> data
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID presenter     state         A     B     C
  <dbl> <chr>         <list>    <int> <int> <int>
1     1 Donatello     <chr [2]>     0     1     1
2     2 Leonardo      <chr [1]>     0     1     0
3     3 Rafael        <chr [2]>     0     0     2
4     4 Michaelangelo <chr [2]>     1     0     1
```

**UPDATE**
As for your second question: the `tidyr` `unnest` function will do this.

```
> data %>%
+   unnest(state)
# A tibble: 7 x 3
     ID presenter     state
  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>
1     1 Donatello     AZ   
2     1 Donatello     NJ   
3     2 Leonardo      NJ   
4     3 Rafael        LA   
5     3 Rafael        MT   
6     4 Michaelangelo PA   
7     4 Michaelangelo LA
```

**UDPATE2**

To count multiple occurrences in the state column you will need an extra loop. This may do it (but suggest you test it):

```
data <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(A = sum(unlist(lapply(list_A, function(x) sum(x == state)))),
         B = sum(unlist(lapply(list_B, function(x) sum(x == state)))),
         C = sum(unlist(lapply(list_C, function(x) sum(x == state)))))
```

For this data:

```
data <- tibble(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  presenter = c("Donatello", "Leonardo", "Rafael", "Michaelangelo"),
  state = list(c("AZ", "NJ"), c("NJ"), c("LA", "MT", "MT", "MT"), c("PA", "PA", "LA")) 
)
```

we would expect extra counts for the third (3x "MT") and fourth (2x "PA") rows for respectively column C and A:

```
> data
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 4 x 6
     ID presenter     state         A     B     C
  <dbl> <chr>         <list>    <int> <int> <int>
1     1 Donatello     <chr [2]>     0     1     1
2     2 Leonardo      <chr [1]>     0     1     0
3     3 Rafael        <chr [4]>     0     0     4
4     4 Michaelangelo <chr [3]>     2     0     1
```

Comment: There's a case I didn't mention, if multiple of the same state is in the cell it must count too; so c("PA" , "PA) would be A = 2.